# JNDI LDAP create 2 connection In the the same InitialDirContext object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi

I need to create 1 ldap connexion (I use a application account )  and from this connection i need to create other connexion (user connection) from check if the uid and password is ok.

```
Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapServerUrl);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");

SearchControls searchCtrls = new SearchControls();
searchCtrls.setReturningAttributes(new String[] {});
searchCtrls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

String filter = "(&(cn=" + identifier + "))";

DirContext ctx = null;
ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(
   ldapBaseDN, filter, searchCtrls);

String fullDN = null;
if (answer.hasMore()) {
    fullDN = answer.next().getNameInNamespace();

    ctx.close();
    ctx = null;

    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, fullDN);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
    // here I must create the user connection for check if the uid and password is good.

    return true;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you find the user in the LDAP DIT you should then modify tne environment to contain the user's DN and password and then issue [`LdapContext.reconnect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/LdapContext.html#reconnect-javax.naming.ldap.Control:A-) using the same `Context`.

You don't need to create a separate 'physical' connection.